# error in installing matplotlib1.5.1 in python3.5

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 'Windows 8'. I installed 'python35-32'  successfully. Then I download 'matplotlib 1.5.1' . But it can not installed . I get an error that required package can not be built.

Comment: Can you please share the relevant parts of the error log or anything that could help with identifying the problem? And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Downvoted, please provide more information. Does your system recognize python when you run `pip` command in command line? Where did you download your files from and what is the exact sequence you carried out to install the above.

Comment: Yes when I run pip it recognize python. I get matplotlib from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib/

Comment: I download from the website. unzip the file. and then run these commands in cmd: cd matplotlib
python setup.py build
python setup.py install

Comment: On windows you should use one of the binary distributions (anaconda, pythonxy, enthought canopy, Christoph Gohlke's packages) rather than trying to build them your self.   Many of the scientific python packages require a properly configure c-compiler (in the case of windows visual studio) to build.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Open cmd with admin privilege. (right click and Run as administrator)
- Enter this command `pip install matplotlib`, and wait for the installation to complete.

#### Alternative:

If you want to keep the wheels for offline installation later, you can do the following:

- Open cmd, and enter this command
- `pip install --download /path/to/some/dir/ matplotlib`. This will download `matplotlib` and all other required wheels in the directory `/path/to/some/dir/`.
- To install, enter this command: `pip install --no-index --find-links /path/to/some/dir/ matplotlib`

Here `/path/to/some/dir/` is the directory where the file gets downloaded. You can use `.` instead of `/path/to/some/dir/` to download in the current directory.

---

#### Edit:

Take a look at matplotlib [installation guide for windows](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#windows). The line most relevant to your case is probably this:

> For Python 3.5 the [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) needs to be installed.

So just install it by following the link and then follow the above procedure. That should do the trick.

Note: They also suggest that the best option is *using one of the pre-packaged python distributions that already provide matplotlib built-in*, like [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/), [miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html) and [canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/). You may want take into consideration too.

---

#### Edits as per your comment

As I have already said, [anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) is a pre-packaged python distribution that includes hundreds of python packages. To quote the [official python page](https://www.python.org/download/alternatives/), anaconda is ***"a full Python distribution for data management, analysis and visualization of large data sets"***. So you can do pretty much everything with anaconda that you can do with the *traditional python* (aka CPython), *plus* you have a great number of popular python packages at your disposal.

To get yourself started with anaconda, you can check this out: [Test drive Anaconda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/test-drive.html).

Comment: ith error code 1 in C:\Users\yas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-i_ssuzg0\numpy
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' comm
and.

C:\Users\yas>-m pip install --upgrade pip
'-m' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\yas>

Comment: @user5882832 check the edited answer. Does it solve the problem?

Comment: @user5882832 what you can do is *start the process all over again*, right from installation of python. Just uninstall python first, delete the python installation directory (eg. `C:\Program Files\Python35-32`) and `C:\user\AppData\Local\pip`, then follow the instructions given in [installation guide for windows](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#windows)

Comment: @user5882832 and remember to install [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) first

Comment: I did. but still nothing happen

Comment: Then I think all I can say is to try anyone of the pre-packaged python distributions like anaconda, etc.

Comment: I install anacoda. Now what do I have to do?

Comment: @Yasamin Take a look at the edited answer. If anaconda helped you accomplish what you wanted, click on the green tick to accept this as answer! You may also want to edit your question, mentioning how you actually got around your original problem, for future readers.

Comment: No Anacoda does not solve my problem. Actually I don't know what to do after installing anacoda. Because python still have an error for matplotlib.

Comment: @Yasamin Did you read my edited answer? If not, then read it first. After reading that you should understand that when you use anaconda, you don't need the traditional python anymore.

Comment: I understood. But again in anacoda also , I saw " no module matplotlib" !

Comment: @Yasamin the first google search I did led me to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053852/how-to-install-matplotlib-for-anaconda-1-9-1-and-python-3-3-4). That should help.